# Where to put Phoenix controllers for app with both web frontend and an API

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm learning Phoenix/Elixir and trying to figure out what the correct convention would be if you had an app using both a web scope and an api scope. At the moment I created another controller for the API, `DatapointApiController`, in the same directory as the web view controller, `DatapointController`.

I'm pretty sure there is a convention around how this should be handled? Where would be a better place to put the controller for the API scope, and where should it be put in the project?

My `router.ex` file should give enough context:

```
defmodule Web.Router do
  use Web.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Web do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
    resources "/datapoints", DatapointController
  end

  scope "/api", Web do
    pipe_through :api
    resources "/datapoints", DatapointApiController, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd do `scope "/api", Web.API` and `resources "/datapoints", DatapointController, only: [:create]` but I don't think there's a universally accepted convention for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current convention seems to be:

- Put the root scope controllers under `web/controllers`, with a name such as `MyApp.FooController`
- Put controllers scoped under other namespaces under `web/controllers/<namespace>` with a name such as `MyApp.<Namespace>.FooController` (for example, `MyApp.API.FooController` under `web/controllers/api`

I usually have a look at the [hex.pm source code](https://github.com/hexpm/hexpm) when I'm confused about conventions and best practices in Phoenix.

Comment: How do i create a namepscape MyApp.<Namespace>.FooController ?